# Rails 3 vestal_versions: Create new version at parent model upon change in child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, vestal-versions

using Rails 3 with the vestal_versions gem and have this situation:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  versioned
  has_many :comments
  (...)
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  (...)
end
```

Versioning of the Post model works flawlessly. What I want is, that as soon as the associated Comment model gets created/updated, the related Post model should get a new version. (I do not have the need for the restoration feature of vestal_versions.)

What would be the right strategy to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `papertrail gem` for this type of tasks, but this should work the same for you.
An idea would be to update the post of the comment, when comment will be created - save will be called on it's post and will create a new version of this post. Something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  after_create :update_post

  def update_post
    self.post.save
  end
end
```

again, probably not the best way as you have to call save on post each time you add a comment and this is a performance issue.

**update** based on `kwirschau` comment

```
  def update_post
    self.post.send(:create_version)
  end
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess this pragmatic approach should do it. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the log:
`self.post.send(:create_version)` does the job with vestal_versions (instead of `self.post.save`). See also: https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions/issues/11